# Dictionary literal contains duplicate keys

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I have a dictionary data of type [[String:AnyObject]] in the format below and my app crashes with **"fatal error: Dictionary literal contains duplicate keys"** whenever I run my App.

I tried to manually delete duplicate data (out of 3000+ records :-() but that didn't work because I may have missed one or two duplicate records.

```
[
    "id": "1",
    "alpha": "A",
    "title": "Title",
    "SubTitle": "Sub Title",
    "Text": "My Text"
],
[
    "id": "2",
    "alpha": "B",
    "title": "Title",
    "SubTitle": "Sub Title",
    "Text": "My Text"
]
```

Any guide on how to remove duplicate keys from dictionary with code would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You have probably an array type containing dictionaries, this is perfectly fine. Add the code where you're processing the object and what you're going to accomplish.

Comment: @vadian thanks for the response. I wish to remove the duplicate keys from the dictionary and I have no idea how to do that. The code I have only displays data from the dictionary and i wrote that before I had so much data in that dictionary.

Comment: I don't see any duplicated keys in your `Dictionary` instance. could you be more precise, please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a way to find the culprit without changing all the original literals:

First, set the type of the array of dictionaries as follows:

```
let dictionaries : [DictionaryLiteral<String, AnyObject>] = [
[
    "id": "1",
    ...
```

Then run the following code:

```
for (i, dict) in dictionaries.enumerate() {
    var keys = Set<String>()
    for (key, _) in dict {
        if keys.contains(key) {
            print("dict[\(i)] contains duplicate key: \"\(key)\"")
        } else {
            keys.insert(key)
        }
    }
}
```

I should point you to the duplicate keys.

Comment: DictionaryLiteral is deprecated since Xcode 10.2, use KeyValuePairs instead (not editing the question in case someone is still on an older version).