# How to remove duplicate keys from dictionary?

Tags: swift, dictionary

I'm using Xcode 13.4. I'm working on a dictionary based app. I've an issue with dictionary that I've thousands of keys in dictionary. Now I've an error

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Dictionary literal contains duplicate keys

How to get ride of this error? I've tried many answers from StackOverFlow but i can't get solution about my lengthy dictionary.

[image]

```
let dict : [String:String] = [
        "ik4":"一",
        "sioh8":"一",
        "cik4": "七",
        "ding1": "丁",
        "diong7": "丈",
        "diong5":"丈",
.........]
```

Comment: Each dictionary key MUST be unique. Its your responsibility if you are trying to create manually dictionary, Keys should be unique.

Comment: What are you going to do with values of duplicating keys? Ignore them or what?

Comment: What @vadian suggest will not throw an error but it will ignore any duplicates meaning the result will be a valid dictionary so it could be a way to solve the issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dictionary literal contains duplicate keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34362170/dictionary-literal-contains-duplicate-keys)

Answer (score 0):

Each dictionary key MUST be unique. Its your responsibility if you are trying to create manually dictionary, Keys should be unique.

As such no api to remove duplicate keys from dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

If it's important to check also the values of the duplicate keys you have to do it *manually*.

If not an easy way to remove the duplicate keys is to make the dictionary a JSON string and decode end re-encode the JSON.

- Copy the entire dictionary literal and paste it into a Playground
- Replace `[]` with `{}` and wrap the literal in `"""` like

  ```
  let dict = """
    {
        "ik4":"一",
        "sioh8":"一",
        "cik4": "七",
        "ding1": "丁",
        "diong7": "丈",
        "diong5":"丈",
        "cik4": "七"
    }
    """
  ```
- Run this code

  ```
  do {
      let input = try JSONDecoder().decode([String:String].self, from: Data(dict.utf8))
      let encoder = JSONEncoder()
      encoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted
      let output = try encoder.encode(input)
      let string = String(data: output, encoding: .utf8)!
      print(string)
  } catch {
      print(error)
  }
  ```
- Copy the result in the Console between `{}` and paste it into your project.